# How to put three conditions in CASE STATEMENT of SQL?

Tags: sql, case

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
,CASE WHEN (ETA>10 OR Class='EOL') THEN 'Eligible' ELSE 'Not Applicable' END AS Eligible
FROM XYZtable
```

The result is:

```
PN  PD  ETA Class   BU  Serial  Comm    frmToday    Eligible
CX  CRD 03-10   IP  07  2322    CARD    3   Not Applicable
BX  CRD 03-18   IP  05  2324    CARD    11  Eligible
MX  CRD 03-10   EOL 07  2325    CARD    3   Not Applicable
```

I want the below mentioned results in the `Eligible` Column:

```
If ETA > 10 THEN 'Eligible'
If Class = 'EOL' THEN 'Consult Plz'
Else 'Not Applicable'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN ETA>10 THEN 'Eligible' 
      WHEN Class = 'EOL' THEN 'Consult Plz' 
      ELSE 'Not Applicable' END AS Eligible
FROM XYZtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE 
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value>
    ELSE <value>
END
```

or if you need to nest you can

```
CASE 
    WHEN <condition> THEN 
        CASE <othercondition> THEN <value>
        ELSE <othervalue> END
END
```

in your `CASE`,

```
CASE 
    WHEN ETA > 10 
        THEN 'Eligible' 
    WHEN Class = 'EOL' 
        THEN 'Consult Plz'
    ELSE 'Not Applicable' 
END
```